# Significance of wire wound resistor

Tags: power-supply, power

I am working on HVAC control panel for 4 wheeler. The circuit for the panel was designed by our previous team. Currently I am facing an issue with a component which is a wirewound resistor in the power supply **R1 30ohm 5W**. The resistor is obsolete now and I have to find replacement for the same.

Please help me understand the significance of this wirewound resistor in the power circuit and what is the criteria for its replacement.

The component ID is ZDA0411.

https://www.vishay.com/docs/21027/z300-c.pdf

[image]

Comment: @AndrewMorton ... my reading of the question ("designed by our previous team") is that OP is in procurement and wants to understand what purpose it has in order to better choose a replacement for manufacturing.

Comment: Who told you that it is obsolete? I find it strange that Vishay would do this without proposing a replacement. I find nothing on their site indicating part status (bad site).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The LM2931 takes input voltages up to 26 V, say 30 V with two fingers crossed.

The MOV1 varistor clamps the input voltage, but it can only do that for limited currents; hence, R1 has to drop the voltage difference between BATTERY_IN's maximum voltage and the ca 30 V that the varistor will regulate to in series with that 30 Ω.

So, you *must* use 30 Ω. It doesn't seem to me that you need any other specifics from that resistor, just that it's roughly 30 Ω, and that it can deal with 5 W.

Seems like a fairly unproblematic thing. Just [search](https://www.digikey.in/short/vv3tv4t7) any of the large distributor inventories for 30 Ω, 5 W, radial or axial resistors.

The fact that it's wirewound doesn't seem very important – it's just that historically, most high-powered resistors were.

Answer (score 3):

Do note, that if the incoming power is very "spiky" say from magneto rectification, a *pulse rated* resistor may be warranted.  It is commonly thought that wirewound resistors are "good" at handling pulses, and this is true if they occur rarely.  But for continuous pulsing, I've personally seen wirewound fail, even at much higher wattage ratings than the pulses.

Comment: you wouldn't normally expect spiky power from a battery. In fact radio operators often run from battery power even when the grid is available *because* batteries are so un-spiky. But yes, valid point, if it's also connected to a certain type of generator then the generator may produce spikes